# pass command line argument/fstream into function

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I invoke my program with the name of a text file, which gets put into argv[2 & 4] (there's two files). I then need this name to get passed into a function. Would it be better to so ifstream myFile(argv[2]) then pass in an ifstream like `void func(ifstream myFile, ifstream myOtherFile)` or should I pass in the argv[2 & 4] itself like `void func(char* nameOne, char* nameTwo)`? If the second way, is that the correct way I would pass that in?

The files are only used within the scope of that function, so I can open and close them in the function, or open them, pass them into the function, then close them after returning from the function. I just would like to know which way would make more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is thematic C++ resource management - whenever possible have the `}` handle clean-up. In your case, this guideline suggests that an automatic duration `ifstream`, which only lives in the scope of `func`, is preferable since it closes the file on destruction. Since `ifstream` is move only, you could call `func` as `func(ifstream(argv[2]), ifstream(argv[4]))`.